# keep BroadcastReceiver alive after onReceive

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have `CallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver` class which records phone calls via `MediaRecorder` instance.
The problem is each time my service receives intent new instance of `PhoneCallReceiver` is created with unitialized recorder.
Therefore I can't stop recording.Of course I can store recorder instance in the static variable but this is dirty hack.
I believe there must be way to keep service alive
Here is my receiver class:

```
public class CallReceiver extends PhoneCallReceiver {
    private static VoiceRecorder recorder; // VoiceRecorder stores MediaRecorder instance 
    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        Log.d("phone","onIncomingCallReceived");
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallAnswered(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        Log.d("phone","onIncomingCallAnswered");
        MainActivity.recorder=new VoiceRecorder("incoming_"+number);
        try {
            MainActivity.recorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("phone error",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end)
    {
        Log.d("phone","onIncomingCallEnded");
        if (MainActivity.recorder!=null) {
            try {
                MainActivity.recorder.stop();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.d("phone record error",e.getLocalizedMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            MainActivity.recorder=null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        Log.d("phone","onOutgoingCallStarted "+MainActivity.recorder);
        MainActivity.recorder=new VoiceRecorder("outgoing_"+number);
        try {
            MainActivity.recorder.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.d("phone error",e.getLocalizedMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end)
    {
        Log.d("phone","onOutgoingCallEnded "+MainActivity.recorder);
        if (MainActivity.recorder!=null) {
            try {
                MainActivity.recorder.stop();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            MainActivity.recorder=null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start)
    {
        Log.d("phone","onMissedCall");
    }

}
```

Comment: Your `PhoneCallReceiver` should not have a `MediaRecorder`. It should delegate to a foreground service that has a `MediaRecorder`. Beyond that, you may want to edit your question with a [mcve] that illustrates your problem.

Comment: @CommonsWare so static variable is ok in this case?PS:updated the post

Comment: "so static variable is ok in this case?" -- no. "Here is my service class" -- that would not appear to be a service. It would appear to be a `BroadcastReceiver`.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks didn't know about foreground services.It works great!Could you post your comment as an answer so I accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `PhoneCallReceiver` should not have a `MediaRecorder`. It should delegate to a foreground service that has a `MediaRecorder`. The service can remain stable. A `BroadcastReceiver` registered in the manifest lives for just one `onReceive()` call, by way of comparison.